# Go to a specific cell in csv in a loop

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

I want to use a loop with the Start loop each row in Automation Anywhere.

If i use the start loop each row in a file, how it is start from a specific Cell.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Automation Anywhere, Go to specific cell command is not available for CSV file. It's available only for the Excel command Operations.

The *`*Read from CSV/Text*`* command uses Comma delimiter to read individual cell in particular row, you can use Filedata Column(column number) to read specific column data. You can use column number, but not the specific cell id. So we have to use Excel Command to navigate specific cell.

- Use Excel Open SpreadSheet command to open the csv file.
- Then Get Cells to Get All Cells in the file.
- Use Each Row in an Excel Dataset loop command to read each row in a file.
- Use Go to Cell to go Specific Cell in csv file. B$Counter$ (B1,B2,..)
- Use Get Cells to get values from Active cell or Specific cell. And
  assign it to Variable.
- . .

Refer below attachment.
[image]
you can use Excel Command operations on particular cell as per your requirements.

Comment: What if I don't have Microsoft office installed in my machine? I am a newbie so I only know CSV as my free alternative. Do recommend me options. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Doesn´t exist an attribute that will let you start from a certain row. But you can use the $Counter$ variable to make it start from certain row. Try something like this inside your loop
[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: Why not use $Counter$ greater than or equal to the row number? and then directly perform the actions?